# how to map 127.0.0.1 to example.com in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

It is possible in SpringBoot to map localhost into example.com like in Laravel, like below?
[How to change localhost url for Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873302/how-to-change-localhost-url-for-laravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following:

`127.0.0.1       example.com`

to your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your hosts file
127.0.0.1 example.com

Or if you are using linux you can set this as your hostname
example.com